# An inequality on a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function ensuring it is a diffeomorphism.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

While rehearsing for a competitive exam, I stumble upon the following question:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ being $\mathcal{C}^1$, assuming there exists $k>0$ such that: $$\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^n,\|f(x)-f(y)\|\geqslant k\|x-y\|,$$ what can be said on $f$?

I am strongly convinced that **$f$ is a $\mathcal{C}^1$-diffeomorphism**. First, notice that the given inequality implies that $f$ is injective ; indeed, if $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are such that $f(x)=f(y)$, then: $$0\geqslant k\|x-y\|.$$
$k$ being strictly positive leads to $\|x-y\|=0$, namely $x=y$. Therefore, according to the inverse function theorem to prove that $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$-diffeomorphism, it suffices to prove that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\mathrm{d}_xf:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is non singular. To do so, my guess is that it would be easier to prove that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\mathrm{d}_xf$ is injective. Indeed, in dimension $1$, the given inequality implies that $f'$ does not vanish. In the multivariate case, I know that: $$\forall(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^n,\|f(x)-f(y)-\mathrm{d}_xf(y-x)\|=o(\|h\|),$$
but I don't know how to handle the little $o$ in my minorations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being $C^1$ we have
$$ \|d_x f(h)\|= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{\|f(x+th)-f(x)\|}{t} \geq k\|h|$$
so the differential is injective and $f$ is a local diffeo. I think that in a 'competitive' exam it may be another aspect which is aimed for: That $f$ is a diffeo onto ${\Bbb R}^n$. This follows from $f({\Bbb R}^n)$ being open (because of being a local diffeo) and closed (because of the Lipshitz expansion condition). The image being open and closed means it equals ${\Bbb R}^n$, since the latter is connected.